# Can I get full height of div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have link : http://batdongsana8.com/1/
Seem that left column can not get full 100% height of screen, if i remove some of articles left column , it works fine !

Anyone can help me to figure out this problem ?
Thank you very much !

Screenshot Problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9lys.jpg

Answer (score 1):

add height to inherit resolve your issue [Learn More Inherit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp)

```
.containerform {
    background-color: beige;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but please read my question carefully ! Your way is not working !

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `overflow: auto;` to your `.col-left` class

```
.col-left {
  float: left;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to appear scroll bar ! Do you have other ways ?